# Using AutoLayout to one label to push another, if its growing

Tags: ios, objective-c

Say i have two labels, close to each ether, and one will maybe grow:

[image]

So if the left label will change and grow, i would like the right label to move to the right and give space, but not squeeze, like so:

[image]

Normally i just use:

```
 CGFloat width =  [self.priceLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]].width;

  self.myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.myLabel.frame.origin.x, self.myLabel.frame.origin.y, width,self.myLabel.frame.size.height);
```

and move the right label to the end of of the left label,
But i'm using AutoLayout and looking for a way to make it possible

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by trying the visual format:

```
NSString *visualFormat = @"|-[label1]-[label2]";
NSLayoutFormatOptions options = NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY | NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeftToRight;
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label1, label2);
NSArray *layoutConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:visualFormat options:options metrics:nil views:views];
[view addConstraints:layoutConstraints];
```

If you also want to add a right margin and any available space in the middle you can use
NSString *visualFormat = @"|-[label1]-@1-[label2]-|";

Check [the visual format guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html) for all possible options.